# Should I return the object itself just for function chain

Tags: oop, functional-programming, coding-style, function-composition

I have been wondering whether should I return the object itself from a setter or procedure (returning `void` originally), so that all the function can chain together.

We've all been taught to return `void` when there is nothing to return, but is returning the object itself better then returning `void`?

Comment: Different communities have different ideas about this. In Python, mutating functions typically return `None`. jQuery ecosystem returns `this` whenever possible; in Ruby one almost never returns `nil` except if the function explicitly does so. There is no objective answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the operation in question is a mutating operation, you don't have any 'natural' return value. This means that you have an opportunity to return whatever you'd like to - for example the object itself.

In OOP, if you return the object itself, you'll effectively enable a [Fluent Interface](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). While this enables method chaining it also exposes you to [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)) issues, so it's an open question whether or not this is a net benefit.

In FP, state mutation breaks [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency), so well-designed FP APIs don't allow setters or mutating operations at all. Instead, you'd use copy-and-update where a function returns a copy of the original input, with a few things changed. This is so common in FP that languages like F# and Haskell has special syntax for such operations.

You can see examples of all three styles (1. mutation, 2. Fluent Interface, 3. Copy-and-update) compared and contrasted in my article [Builder isomorphisms](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/02/10/builder-isomorphisms).

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. I found many concepts I have never heard. I have been in C# and Go, and got confused by the concept of functions/methods and mutability. I got a bit clearer after reading this answer and learning Haskell.